# .Net MongDB Driver more than 5x slower than pymongo equivalent

Tags: c#, mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-.net-driver

I have a collection with ~8.5k documents.
This Python code gets the last added document in ~50-70ms:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
import pymongo, time

client = MongoClient(connectionString)
db = client[databaseName]
collection = db[collectionName]

tic = time.perf_counter()
collection.find({}).sort([("Timestamp", pymongo.DESCENDING)]).limit(1)[0]
toc = time.perf_counter()
print("Took {0} seconds".format(toc - tic))
```

While this equivalent C# code requires ~300-400ms:

```
var start = Environment.TickCount;
var doc = dbcollection.Find(new BsonDocument()).Sort(Builders<BsonDocument>.Sort.Descending("Timestamp")).Limit(1).ToList();
var end = Environment.TickCount;
Console.WriteLine(end-start);
```

My question is: Where is this performance difference coming from and how can i improve the C# speeds?

Other things to mention:

- The Timestamp field is indexed
- .Net MongoDB driver version is: 2.14.1
- pymongo version: 4.0.2
- MongoDB version: 4.4.0 Community
- Avg. document size is ~840 Bytes

Comment: The performance issue is probably the driver used to connect to the database which is in the connection string.